# Java: JPA / JSON / REST roundtrip workflow

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa, mapping

I'm look for a java "workflow" which does the following:

1. Fetch Object from database
2. Serialize it to json
3. Take it back
4. Update the database

This has to be "plain" Java. By which I mean no full stack frameworks like Spring or Seam or similar.

Currently I'm using MySQL/JPA/Hibernate for ORM, Jackson for JSON mapping and AngularJS on the client-side.

This is all fine and dandy for simple objects. But as the objects get more complex I find myself writing more and more mapping code.

For example consider this (simplified) objects:

```
class Website {
    long id;
    String name;
    List<Domain> domains;
}
class Domain {
    long id;
    String url;
    Set<String> countries;
}
```

which will map to the three tables: `Website`, `Domain`, `Country`

Jackson does a fine job serializing this to somethink like (again simplified):

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "My Website"
    domains: [ {
        id: 1,
        url: "www.mysite.de",
        countries: [ "de" ]
    }, {
        id: 2,
        url: "www.mysite.com",
        countries: [ "uk", "us" ]
    } ]
}
```

which Angular can handle pretty well.

But after working with it on the client I might get this in an POST request:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "My Website"
    domains: [ {
        id: 1,
        url: "www.mysite.de",
        countries: [ "de", "at", "ch" ]
    }, {
        url: "www.mysite.co.uk",
        countries: [ "uk" ]
    }, {
        url: "www.mysite.us",
        countries: [ "us" ]
    } ]
}
```

This can be mapped to corresponding Java objects by Jackson but *not stored* in the database in this form.

Now I have to start "analysing" the created java object and:

1. fetch the correct old object
2. copy the data of the new object into the old and take care of:
3. delete sub-objects which aren't there anymore
4. update those that have changed
5. insert new ones
6. then merge it back into the database

which gets pretty messy as the objects get larger and contain more and deeper reference chains.

So is there a better way of updating the database objects manually? Or are there any tools which provide help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say no frameworks then list several frameworks you are using. Why the inconsistent requirements?

Comment: I didn't find better names for this than "Frameworks like Spring or Seam". ... hm. perhaps "whole stack frameworks"? In difference I would rather call Jackson a "library". Or a "component". Wording is a little bit difficult here.

Comment: Hibernate is definitely a framework... :) Anyhow I've posted some suggestions in an answer. Good luck :)

Comment: But rather than just saying "without using frameworks" explain why you can't use them. Because it is possible that something from the frameworks might be useful (for example Spring Data) and might be useable even if you can't use the full framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a NoSQL database such as MongoDB you can just store your POJO generated by Jackson into the database and query/retrieve it.

If not then just set up your Jackson annotations to map the fields from JSON to Java differently or your hibernate mappings to map from Java to Database differently and match everything up that way.

If you really can't make it work that way then have "client side" objects and "server side" objects - then give each one a constructor that builds it from the other.

Then you can just do:

```
ClientFoo in = ...;
ServerFoo serverIn = new ServerFoo(in);
// Save to database



// Later
serverFoo out = ...;
ClientFoo clientOut = new ClientFoo(out);
// Send to client.
```

This at least keeps all the data mapping code in one place and encapsulates it away from everything else.

Comment: hi Tim. Thanks for your quick reply. NoSQL is not an option. What I'm doing currently is essentially what you are suggesting. I've edited a litte to make this more clear. (I hope). What I'm looking for is a better / more automatic / more magic way of doing it ;)